# Html.ActionLink with a specified HTML id?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper, actionlink

I'd like to give the like generated with an `Html.ActionLink` an HTML id so I can change the CSS depending on where I am. I have a `MasterPage` with a set of links and I'd like to distinguish the active "Tab" with Jquery changing the css of that active #id

Right now I'm using:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Some View", "Index", "controller")%>
```

It generates:

```
<a href="/controller">Some View</a>
```

I'd like to generate:

```
<a id="something" href="/controller">Some View</a>
```

Is that possible? I've tried:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Some View", "Index", "controller", new {id="blahbla")%>
```

But that generates:

```
<a href="/controller/Length?5">Some View</a>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the correct syntax, but should that `{` really not be closed?

Comment: It should, but i would have thought the web server would have generated an error, when they tried to run that web page. I think it's a typo.  Can the original poster confirm please?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You were on the right track.  I am not sure why it didn't work for you as your code has a typo which would have produced a `} expected` error. The following is what you are looking for:

```
 <%= Html.ActionLink("Test Link", "SomeAction", "SomeController",
         null, new {id = "someID" }) %>
```

Which produces teh following HTML:

```
<a href="/SomeController/SomeAction" id="someID">Test Link</a>
```

**Edit:** I just realized what the issue is because I was mis-reading what you tried.  You are using the wrong overload to pass in the `id` html element.  Your probably passing the `new { id="blah" }` param into the `routeValues` parameter, which will cause it to be used when building the route link, rather than the `htmlAttributes` paramater which is what you want.

I think you are using:

```
ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes)
```

When what you need to use is the following overload like I did above in my answer:

```
ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName,
    Object routeValues, Object htmlAttributes)
```

Which makes sure `new { id="blah" }` is being passed into the `htmlAttributes` param.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Some View", "Index", "controller", null, new {id="something}")%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically it's giving an error because there is no method overload that has the signature you want.

The closest signature to the one that you need is

```
public static string ActionLink(
this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
string linkText,
string actionName,
string controllerName,
Object routeValues,
Object htmlAttributes
```

)

You are passing the id attribute into the routevalue which is why it's giving you the funny href. pass null into the routevalue, then add your htmlattributes

Answer (score 2):

try this

```css
@Html.ActionLink("Forgot your access?", "RecoverPassword", 
"Account", new { area = "registration-full.html" }, 
new { @class = "col-xs-6", id = "login-forget-link" })
```