# Click event not firing on link generated with Html.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an ActionLink as below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("-Pg", "SupprimerPage", "Section", 
new { pageId = @item.Id }, new { @id = "ConfirmDeletePage", @class = "editLink", style 
= "width:30px" })
```

And my script:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#ConfirmDeletePage', function () {
        var x=confirm("Confirm delete page?");
        console.log(x);
        if (x == true){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

When I use a hardcoded link with the `<a>` tag, it works fine.  But when I try to generate the link using  `Html.ActionLink`, the event handler is not called.  any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$("...").click(function () { }) not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755927/clickfunction-not-working)

Comment: View the generated HTML source in the browser and check that the ID is correctly injected.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: ID checked and is correct.

Comment: Also note: delegated events, attached to `document`, do not require a DOM ready handler as `document` always exists (not the bug, just a note) :)

Comment: What is the HTML?  Is the same `id` re-used anywhere?

Comment: @David: Yes it is reused as I have several same elements.

Comment: @tabby: Then your markup is invalid, so the behavior of the JavaScript is undefined.  Correct your markup first.

Comment: Ok, I used a class, however, when I click on Yes, the method in the ActionLink is not being called.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

For your problem "when I click on Yes, the method in the ActionLink is not being called" this is because you are returning yes on yes button so after execute your function it follow link "href" that's why it seems the method in the ActionLink is not being called, just return false or use  `event.preventDefault();` inside of true section which run on press yes button

```js
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.editLink', function (event) {
            var x=confirm("Confirm delete page?");
            console.log(x);
            if (x == true){
     
              return true;
    
            }
            else {
                alert('Pressed NO')
                return false;
            }
        });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://hello.com" class="editLink" >Click me !</a>
```

for more go with this [**anchor-tag-with-javascript-onclick-event**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347786/html-anchor-tag-with-javascript-onclick-event)

Comment: I don't understand why I should return false in both cases.  Doing so, keeps the dialog from popping up again and again.

Comment: return false in  not for keeps the dialog from popping up again and again, this is for stop action link to follow it's url, and you can run some JavaScript on click of yes button,

Comment: Ok. But I want the method, that is, the action link to follow the url when I click on OK.  If I click on Cancel or close the dialog, the method should not be called.

Comment: than simple return true will work, you just need to Use class Instead of id (because your id not unique) , i have updated my code please have a look

Comment: No this does not work either.  The dialog is opened.  I click on OK, the dialog is re loaded again and the method is not called.  I click on Cancel, the dialog is re loaded and method again not called.

Comment: have you tried  code snippet in my answer is this what you want exactly in your scenario    ?

Answer (score 0):

If it works with a hardcoded link, but not when you use an ActionLink, that means the ActionLink must be generating something different to your hardcoded link, which means your jQuery selector (`#ConfirmDeletePage`) is not finding the element.

You can confirm this by using your browser's developer tools to inspect the `<a...` tag generated by the ActionLink.

Based on the question [Html.ActionLink with a specified HTML id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622590/html-actionlink-with-a-specified-html-id) maybe you need to change `@id = "ConfirmDeletePage"` to `id = "ConfirmDeletePage"`.